# MOSFET failure in DC-DC switching converter

Tags: mosfet, step-down, failure

I am using the following circuit to drive a 220 W heating load. The Vin is 24 V. The MOSFETs Q1 and Q2 are CSD18503Q5AT. The LM27222 is driven by an ATMEGA328P at 5 V with a PWM at 62 kHz.

[image: Circuit schematic]

We noticed a board failure where the MOSFET and the driver failed. Is it possible that the failure is caused by switching on/off of the circuit fast?

After switching off the circuit the voltage goes down with delay. The atmega is still working, in this transitional phase, because it is powered by a TRACO TSR-1 2450. Does this cause a failure of the MOSFETs and driver?

Edited:

Value of C4=550 uF

Value of L1=12 uH

There is the same LC filter (with the same values above) at the input voltage.

Comment: This of course can't be answered. You should provide the exact schematics with values, further some description on how it worked and when exactly it failed,

Comment: Have you done any osciloscope measurements ? There might be some inductive spike damaging those MOSFETs. Other possibility is too short dead time, but the driver seems to be "smart" and prevents that. PCB image will also help.

Comment: It failed due to choice of LC values most likely amplifying at resonance. No values.

Comment: The LC filter may be causing shootthru due to lack of additional deadtime in gate control. Driver is only 10ns deadtime.

Comment: Scope the supply noise current and show it. AC coupled into a 50 ohm load

Comment: I edit the question with the values. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Whoa! That's about 175 % current ripple at 50 % duty cycle. Is that by design?

Comment: *I am using the following circuit to drive a 220 W heating load.* — **Why?** — A heater is indifferent to the voltage. You need to control the average current. You don't need that circuit, a simple PWM to a low-side connected MOSFET suffices.

Comment: @winny How did you calculate that?

Comment: U= L*di/dt. Differentiate to Ut=LI and solve for I. I assumed 50 % duty cycle.

Comment: @Janka I do not agree. The OP might need the load to be ground referenced, and therefore need to drive the heater high-side. We are not aware about possible EMI due to low-side driving of a 10A load. If the load is slightly inductive, you will end up with some nasty EMI at 62 KHz.

Comment: @Francesco K = Kelvin. k = kilo.

Comment: @winny, let's keep focused on the question, rather than pointing out meaningless typos