# DC-DC step down converter frequency isssue

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, push-pull

I want to power a heating element (24V,2.5A maximum). I decided to use a push-pull configuration with LM27222.

Here is attached the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fesS37.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The PWM signal is generated by an ATMEGA328P at 5V.

Here are some oscilloscope results at different PWM frequency (Probe connected in parallel with the LOAD):

**1kHz without LOAD**

[image: 1kHz without LOAD]

**1kHz with LOAD**

[image: 1kHz with LOAD]

**60Hz without LOAD**

[image: 60Hz without LOAD]

[image: 60Hz without LOAD]

**60Hz with LOAD**

[image: 60Hz with LOAD]

[image]

[image]

Do you have any clues why at the small frequency the output is not stable as at higher frequency? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Highly insufficient bootstrap capacitance for 60 Hz, but the elephant in the room is why you would go to all this hassle over a heating element when a single low side NFET would have sufficed.

Comment: Hi @winny. I found out that a single NFET is not as efficient as this solution. With a standard NFET you got a high loss of power on the MOSFET. Which NFET do you suggest? If you check at 10A the losing power on the MOSFET become quite high. (like the other question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/568276/mosfet-failure-in-dc-dc-switching-converter) 

By the way, thank you for the confirmation about bootstrap capacitance!

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? Any NFET with sufficient low Rds(on) to not cause any problem, low enough Vgsth to be fully switched on by your MCU and enough Vds to survive your worst case input voltage plus margin. Your question is unfortunately an example of an XY problem. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: You could be right. Probably I was too unlucky to find the correct NFET for my problem ;)

Comment: 31,237 to choose from on DigiKey so I'm fully confident you will find one! :-)